# MongoMapper + Rails associations don't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I want to have an ECardMatch that is associated to two Users, and to be able to create through associations like this `@user.ecard_matches.new` etc...

I am able to do something like this:

```
user = User.new
user.ecard_matches
```

This returns an `[]` empty array

But I can't do

```
em = EcardMatch.new
user.ecard_matches << em
```

Error:

```
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?
```

or
`user.ecard_matches.new`

Error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `new' for []:Array
```

Maybe something is wrong with my associations in the model. I am new to rails and mongodb so maybe this kind of usage is bad practice...

User class:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document

  attr_accessor :password

  key :name, String
  key :perika, Integer
  key :digest_password, String

  many :ecard_matches
end
```

EcardMatch class:

```
class EcardMatch
  include MongoMapper::Document

  key :wager, Integer
  key :turn, Integer
  key :first_user_score, Integer
  key :second_user_score, Integer

  belongs_to :first_user, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :second_user, class_name: "User"

end
```

Comment: Can you provide the backtrace for the `NoMethodError`?  The `<<` syntax should work, but you want `user.ecard_matches.build` instead of `user.ecard_matches.new`

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.new 
user.ecard_matches << EcardMatch.new(:prop1=> '....', :prop1=> '....', ...)
user.ecard_matches << EcardMatch.new(:prop1=> '....', :prop2=> '....', ....)
user.save
```

Could this example be helpful ?

Comment: I'm afraid not
NoMethodError: You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?